# Change to sty file does not affect usage

Tags: miktex2.9

I changed a command in one of the sty files of a template. Sadly using this command still gives the old result. I am running MikTex 2.9 and ran

```
initex --update-fndb
```

Still there was no change. I tried removing the template from the root directories and addning again but it still did not change anything. Also rebooting had no effect.

Is there some kind of cache I need to clear for my change to take effect?

Edit:

Here is the command I changed:

from

```
\def\referee#1#2{\@ifnextchar[{\referee@three{#1}{#2}}{\referee@two{#1}{#2}}}
\def\referee@two#1#2{
  \gdef\referee{Supervisor 1: #1\\Supervisor 2: #2}
}
```

to

```
\def\referee#1#2{\@ifnextchar[{\referee@three{#1}{#2}}{\referee@two{#1}{#2}}}
\def\referee@two#1#2{
  \gdef\referee{Supervisor: #1\\Contact for exercise: #2}
}
```

Comment: Normally you should not even have to refresh the FNDB if you only modify the contents of a file. Maybe there are different versions of the same file (with the same name) on your machine and TeX picks up a version you have nor modified. Check the `.log` file for the location of the file that TeX loads. Needless to say that it is generally considered bad practice to modify system-installed `.sty` files of packages released on CTAN or elsewhere.

Comment: I know it is bad practice to modifie the `sty` file but in my case there is no other option because my supervisor wants the change for my report. His request differs from the official university template so I need to change it. However, I don't think there is another version of the file since the compliation does not work due to a `not found` error if I rename the file.

Comment: Mhhh, are you sure the changes you applied will do what you think they should do? If TeX finds the file and it has been modified (i.e. your changes were written to the file, I'm mentioning that because I've had that happen to me a few times before, I thought I had modified the file and saved the changes, but if I reopened the file with a different editor the changes had not been written out), then that seems to be the next best explanation.

Comment: They have been written out (still there after the reboot). I'll add the command into my question. I am pretty sure that it just creates a text on the title page and I had to change two words in the text.

Comment: Without more context and a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) this is all speculation. The definition of `\referee` has another branch involving `\referee@three`. If that one is taken and you did not modify it, you may not see a difference. (I'd like to add that this particular definition of `\referee` looks a bit risky as invoking `\referee{A}{B}` changes the definition of `\referee` so that subsequent invocations of the same code yield wildly different results.)

Comment: ... But maybe there is something else to it: Maybe you don't use `\referee` at all and the output you are seeing is caused by a different command or setting.

Comment: I also changed referee@three but it is only used if 3 names are given. I tried on another machine now and it works... I have no idea what caused the problem.